# MySQL query optimization for max value

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to see if a particular hashcode is within the newest 1000 inserts for a table, what is the most efficient technique to achieve this query:

```
SELECT a.idsearch
  FROM searches a
 WHERE a.hashcode = 549716444      
   AND a.idsearch > (SELECT MAX(b.idsearch) - 1000 
                       FROM searches b);
```

idsearch is an auto_increment column and is the PK.

Comment: And what guarantees do you have, that there are no gaps in `idsearch`?

Comment: I'm trying to see if a particular search has been performed in the last 1000 searches.

Comment: The long of it is that this is for a caching mechanism that pushes search results into 1000 cache tables that get assigned based off idsearch % 1000.  I'm attempting to see if a particular search is still in the cache tables.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? You can use [`SHOW INDEX FROM ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your existing query but add two indexes if they don't already exist:

- A single column index on (idsearch)
- A multi-column index on (haschode, idsearch)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a.idsearch` is an auto-incrementing primary key then you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT a.idsearch
FROM searches a
WHERE a.hashcode = 549716444
ORDER BY a.idsearch DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

This will give you the newest `idsearch` first, so adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: This will return the most recent results for the hashcode. I'm trying to find if a hashcode is in the most recent X recrods.